# what's the best way to use .ai files as icons in HTML?

Tags: html, css, icons, adobe-illustrator

I have custom icons in `.ai` format and when I convert them to `.svg` or `.jpg` ..etc it decrease their quality. And I tried to use IcoMoon so i can use them as fonts but it didn't works well the quality was very bad.

What's the ideal way to use it in HTML code with best quality possible ?

Comment: When you convert them to SVG, what loss in quality do you see? Maybe provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This is an illustrator question. Any loss of quality in an SVG has to do with how you are exporting them. Jpg is raster format and should be avoided for icons.